Yajra Datatables can't filter data when using redis cache
I'm implementing caching using Redis to cache my query. When I display all the data, it works perfectly.
However, the error occurs when I apply any of the manual filters I've created. It returns the following exception:
Exception Message: Method Yajra\DataTables\CollectionDataTable::where does not exist.
This is very strange because when I don't use caching, the query works perfectly.
Please helpppp
here is the preview for some of my codes.
Controller.php
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $query = Cache::remember('dayoff_all_datas', 1800, function () {
                $data = Dayoff::with('pegawaiRelasi:kode_pegawai,full_name');

                if (!Auth::user()->can('dayoff-confirm')) {
                    $data->where('kode_pegawai', Auth::user()->kode_pegawai);
                }

                return $data->get(); // Do not call ->get() here
            });

            // Pass the query to DataTables::eloquent
            return DataTables::of($query)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                // Some columns using rendered blade templating
                ->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    if ($request->filled("dayoff_for")) {
                        $query->where('dayoff_for', "=", $request->dayoff_for);
                    }

                    if ($request->filled("kode_pegawai")) {
                        $query->where('kode_pegawai', "LIKE", "%{$request->kode_pegawai}%");
                    }

                    if ($request->filled("status")) {
                        $query->where('status', "=", $request->status);
                    }

                    if ($request->filled("startDate") && $request->filled("endDate")) {
                        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->startDate, $request->endDate]);
                    }
                })
                // ->orderColumn('created_at', '-created_at $1')
                ->rawColumns(['status', 'kode_pegawai', 'created_at', 'tgl_dari', 'actions'])
                ->toJson();
        }

        return view('dashboard.dayoff.index');
    }

js/collect/showData.js
export function showDatatables() {
  // Initialize DataTable
  let table = $('#table-dayoff').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    responsive: true,
    "lengthMenu": [15, 25, 50, 75, 100, -1],
    ajax: {
      url: dayoffIndex,
      data: function (d) {
        d.dayoff_for = $('#dayoff-for').val();
        d.kode_pegawai = $('#kode-pegawai').val();
        d.status = $('#status').val();
        d.startDate = $('#datepicker-range-start').val();
        d.endDate = $('#datepicker-range-end').val();
      }
    },
    columns: [
    // some columns
],
    // some configuration
  });

  $('#cari').click(function () {
    // get value from input filters
    const filters = ['#dayoff-for', '#kode-pegawai', '#status', '#datepicker-range-start',
      '#datepicker-range-end'
    ].map(selector => $(
      selector).val());

    // cek if the value is null
    if (filters.some(value => value !== '')) {
      table.draw();
    }
  });

  // if clear button clicked
  $('#clear').click(function () {
    // get all value from input filter
    const filters = ['#dayoff-for', '#kode-pegawai', '#status', '#datepicker-range-start',
      '#datepicker-range-end'
    ].map(selector => $(
      selector).val());
    // check if filter is null
    if (filters.some(value => value !== '')) {

      // nullify all the values
      $('#dayoff-for').val('');
      $('#kode-pegawai').val('');
      $('#status').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
      $('#datepicker-range-start').val('');
      $('#datepicker-range-end').val('');

      table.draw();
    }
  });
}

here's some pics:
datatables can show all of the data

but if i select to filter

it will give me the error like this:

I've tried many solutions and none of them is work.
ive do code like this
Cache::remember('cacheName', 300, function(){
   $query = someModels::with('someRelation')->latest

   return Datatables::of($query)
          ->toJson();
});

but it still doesnt work.
I've tried using Eloquent, collections, and other similar approaches, but I still encounter the same issue.
